# I have an activity in which edittext is there and when I click on edittext to open keyboard the apps crashed and restarted why?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have not written anything in my activity Class.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }
}
```

activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#ffff">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_comment_text_background"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/numberlayout">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone_verify"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:hint="Enter Number"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:textSize="20sp">
        </EditText>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right">

            <Button
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/next_verify"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:text="Next"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_button_color_grey">
                <requestFocus/>
            </Button>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".ui.activity.LoginActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            />
```

I'm trying to make login activity so that anyone can login with a mobile number but when I click on edit text to open keyboard app crashes.why?
Can anyone pls help to solve the problem.
The phone on which I m testing is Sony Xperia m2 and its ram is 1 GB.

Below is the logcat when I click on edit text.
Any help will be appreciated.

LogCat

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)

04-06 15:11:53.452 13289-13289/com.test.app E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
04-06 15:11:53.462 13289-13289/com.test.app E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
    android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4175)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:89)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Comment: Looking at your error, it's a memory allocation problem. "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 106 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 3GB until OOM"

Comment: You need to filter Logs . Add the crash logs only which will be in `warn` or `error` logs . What i see is `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. And your code is not enough to find the issue .

Comment: I have seen that error but what I have only the editText that is causing the problem

Comment: android:largeHeap="true"..add this to manifest file

Comment: `Failed to allocate a 106 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 3GB until OOM` there is something very strange with your device. Try another device. For me this line of log looks like your device is bugged

Comment: check all background resource file size you have used in your project,mainly in layout xml file.. image file size creating the issue

Comment: I understand the code is not enough to find the issue but I have activity in which when user click on login he will redirected to this page and in this loginactivity I have the only code written which i have posted here.

Comment: see the updated Logcat I'm not able to understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ckeck your xml file without your drawable of course. So your problem could be from your drawable, so check their size, too large size may crash your application, you can also have an API error if you phone is less than 24 API and if your drawable are in drawable-24 folder, but I don't think this is the problem. If the problem is not above, your phone is propably the cause of the crash, so check with another phone if you can.

Comment: Ok let me check with other device too.

Comment: I tried with another device in some devices it is working but one more device in which it is crashing i.e. vivo android version 6.0

Comment: You have check you "drawable-v24" file ? (in app/src/main/res). If their anything execpt "ic_launcher_foreground", your application may don't work. Because your device is less than 24 API. If your application work on 24 API Device and don't work on less API, you should check this way.

Comment: yes there was a file and I removed that file still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution. I just created and intalled release.apk to the phone it worked for me.
But can anyone tell what is the cause in debug.apk which crashes my app?